# Writing data structures to use different cache lines per threads to avoid thread thrashing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, caching, concurrency

If a data structure is read (Q: write too?) by multiple threads there will be no "thread thrashing" if the threads are accessing different cache lines.

Would anyone who has experience in this area be able to share some code/advice how they ensured/determined where the cache lines begun/end? On something like an array of vector this is relatively easy, but what about for a `std::unordered_map` or `std::set`?

**How would you enforce the data accessed by different threads to be on different cache lines in such a data structure?**

One idea is to just "pad-out" each data structure item to be at least the length of the cache line but then this wastes cache-space, surely?

If the above could be proven to always work would this technique be a type of "lock-free" or even possibly "wait-free" data structure?

Comment: Far as I remember, you need to get your allocated parts severly over-aligned. You can do that with a custom allocator (The last parameter of allocator-aware standard containers).

Comment: If it is only read, there's no chance of cache-ping-pong. That only happens because one processor stakes out a line for itself, gets it stolen, and then the game repeats. No need to claim undivided sovereignty for reading. Look in the processor manual for cache-line size, it is different for different ones.

Comment: It might be useful to mention the MESI protocol at this point. Read-only data is in state Shared, which explains why there's no ping-pong.

Comment: Try looking for the term [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) instead of thread thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

The nodes of a set are distributed pretty randomly in memory, and are therefore unlikely to share cache lines. But since you'd lock an entire set in memory before writing to it, there's little risk of thrashing anyway.